# Google url shortener iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, xcode7, afnetworking-3

Trying to get a short version of URL using GoogleShortener API.
I am using AFNetworking 3.0 and i get this error: 'AnyObject is not a subtype of 'NSProxy'

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    let params = ["longUrl": "MYURL"]


    manager.POST("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MYKEY", parameters: params, success: {(operation: NSURLSession!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("JSON" + responseObject.description)
        },


                 failure: { (operation: NSURLSession!,error: NSError!) in
        println("Error while requesting shortened: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

it is highlighted on line 'println("JSON" + responseObject.description)'
on the begging of 'description'.

Comment: To clarity, are you getting a syntax error? Or is it an error when the code in run?

Comment: @Ollie Type errors are at compilation time, not at runtime.

Comment: It's a syntax error. I don't have API Key in AppDelegate, can it be the problem?

Comment: I guess you'll need a key to perform the shortening, but it shouldn't be showing a type error. Assuming your code is the same as the code you have posted. @EricD Thanks, I'll consult the coffee machine before the silly comments next time!

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? It is just that you're using`println` instead of `print`?

Comment: 2.0 with print I get also error.  I wonder how to add Key to AppDelegate, Google Documentation isn't very clear.

Comment: http://i66.tinypic.com/10f12mh.png

Comment: So if you change it to `print`, you still get the error? I find that Xcode can be silly like that sometimes! If you remove the `.description` does the error still appear?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while using AFNetworking 3.  Documentation indicated that there were some changes.  However, here is the code that I was able to run.  Hope it works out.

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
let params = ["longUrl": "MYURL"]


manager.POST("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MYKEY", parameters: params, success: {(operation: NSURLSessionDataTask!,responseObject: AnyObject?) in
    print("JSON" + (responseObject?.description)!)
    },


             failure: { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask?,error: NSError) in
    print("Error while requesting shortened: " + error.localizedDescription)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
Refer this URL : http://cungcode.com/how-to-use-google-url-shortener-api-ios/

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    let params = ["longUrl": "YOUR_URL]
    manager.POST("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MYKEY", parameters: params, success: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
            }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Comment: swift 3.0 compatible?

Comment: Nope, its 2.2 compatible. You can add it and solve warnings so it will get converted automatically.